# Reflection groups, geometric group theory: John Meier

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, geometric-group-theory, reflection

[image]

This image is from John Meier's *Introduction to the geometry of infinite groups* on p. 47, where reflection groups are being introduced.

Now the claim is, that every edge in the tiling can be labelled either as $r,b$ or $g$ (which is also indicated by the different line styles in the picture).

This makes total sense. However, it is also being mentioned that $r, rgr$ and $rbr$ are the reflections in the sides of the triangle immediately above the gray triangle $\mathbb{T}$ in this tiling.

He explains that we can flip the triangle above down to $\mathbb{T}$ via $r$, then apply $g$ to reflect it to the left of $\mathbb{T}$ and after applying $r$ once again, we are in the desired position.

---

I'm still confused. After reflecting the triangle above $\mathbb{T}$, let's call it $\mathbb{T}'$, down to $\mathbb{T}$ via $r$, we have $r\mathbb{T}' = \mathbb{T}$. That's fine. Applying $g$ to reflect $r\mathbb{T}' = \mathbb{T}$ to the left is also fine, so we are now on the left side of $\mathbb{T}$, precisely at $rg\mathbb{T}'$.

But why can we reflect $rg\mathbb{T}'$ via $r$? The way I see it is that we can only reflect along the three "walls" (the three different line styles in each triangle) but **not** along the tip of the cone, can we?

The intuitive picture I am having in mind is this: Let's say we reflect the gray triangle $\mathbb{T}$ via $g$ to the left $g\mathbb{T}$. What I have in mind is that $g\mathbb{T}$ has the three walls:

$g$ is the "right wall", $r$ is the "left wall" and $b$ is the bottom wall of $g\mathbb{T}$.

In other words, if I were to apply $g$ and then $r$, I would move $\mathbb{T}$ as pictured here:

[image]

(sorry for the messy picture)

I hope I managed to express my confusion appropriately.

So my actual question: If the reflections on every single triangle are presicely $r,g,b$, then why is $rgr\mathbb{T}'$ the triangle on the left side of the triangle $\mathbb{T}'$ right above $\mathbb{T}$ rather than the left most triangle as pictured in my second picture?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r$, $g$, $b$ are 3 fixed lines of reflection, determined by the sides of the grey triangle in your first picture. Any point, hence any triangle, can be reflected across these fixed lines $r$, $g$, $b$. The meaning of "reflection across $r$" doesn't change based on which triangle you are reflecting. You are always reflecting across the same line.

Your last picture is incorrect: When you reflect $g\mathbb{T}$ by $r$, the reflection takes place over the original line $r$, the dark solid side of the original grey triangle $\mathbb{T}$. It does not mean to reflect $g\mathbb{T}$ across the dark solid side of $g\mathbb{T}$. After you perform the reflection of $g\mathbb{T}$ across $r$, you get the triangle directly above $g\mathbb{T}$. This is the same triangle as the reflection of $\mathbb{T}'$ across the side $g'$ (by which I mean the grey solid side of $\mathbb{T}'$), which is the point the author is making.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification @Ted. If i am not mistaken, these lines $r,g,b$ are _not_ just the walls of the gray triangle $\mathbb{T}$ but they are infinite lines (say hyperplanes), am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you @Ted.